# git post-receive hook to clean install node dependencies only if package-lock.json has changed

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to write a git hook to run some tasks when changes are pushed to a remote repository.

The repository is not bare because of the needs of the production environment.

I've got this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "===> post-receive hook fired <==="

# echo pwd is $PWD

cd  /home/pi/production/drawbots/finals/BotClient
echo "Firing in directory: "
pwd

echo "---> checking for new dependencies <---"

# Trying it the conditional way:
if [ git diff HEAD^ HEAD --name-only | grep --quiet "package-lock.json" ];
then
    echo"Clean installing node_modules"
    npm ci
fi

# Trying it the looping way:
#while read line; do
#    echo $line
#      [[ $line == *package-lock.json*  ]] && echo "clean install of node_modules" ; npm ci
#  done < <(git diff HEAD^ HEAD --name-only)


echo "---> building from source code <---"
npx tsc


echo "===> post-receive hook finished <==="
```

The problem I'm running into is in the diff checks.

If I do it the first way with the conditionals:

```
if [ git diff HEAD^ HEAD --name-only | grep "package-lock.json" ];
then
    echo"Clean installing node_modules"
    npm ci
fi
```

I hit errors with the output of the diff not being piped correctly to the grep:

[image: fails in the conditionals]

If I try it the second way with the loop:

```
while read line; do
    echo $line
      [[ $line == *package-lock.json*  ]] && echo "clean install of node_modules" ; npm ci
  done < <(git diff HEAD^ HEAD --name-only)
```

I get a weird error that I'm not in a git repository even though I definitely am.

[image: looping errors]

I'm not great at bash scripts so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with some people in one of my community slack teams someone pointed out that if all I'm trying to do is see if one file (`package-lock.json`) has changed, I could:

- Create a hash of the `package-lock.json` file
- Compare that to a previously stored hash
- If the hash is the same, skip the clean install
- If the hash is different, store the new hash and perform the clean install

This is what my post-receive git hook looks like now:

```
echo "===> post-receive hook fired <==="

cd  /home/pi/production/drawbots/finals/BotClient
echo "Firing in directory: "
pwd

# Prep some vars
GIT_DIRECTORY=/home/pi/production/drawbots
BOT_DIRECTORY=$GIT_DIRECTORY/finals/BotClient
HASH_DIRECTORY=$GIT_DIRECTORY/deployment_tooling
HASH_FILE_NAME=previous_package_lock_hash.txt
HASH_FILE_PATH=$HASH_DIRECTORY/$HASH_FILE_NAME


# Manage package.json hash stuff
mkdir -p $HASH_DIRECTORY
touch $HASH_FILE_PATH

# Compare hashes
CURRENT_FILE_HASH=`md5sum $BOT_DIRECTORY/package-lock.json`
PREVIOUS_FILE_HASH=`cat $HASH_FILE_PATH`
#echo "Current: $CURRENT_FILE_HASH"
#echo "Previous: $PREVIOUS_FILE_HASH"

echo "---> checking for new dependencies <---"

if [[ "${CURRENT_FILE_HASH%%[[:space:]]*}" != "${PREVIOUS_FILE_HASH%%[[:space:]]*}"  ]];
#if [[ $CURRENT_FILE_HASH != $PREVIOUS_FILE_HASH ]];
then
    echo $CURRENT_FILE_HASH > $HASH_FILE_PATH
    echo "package-lock.json has been updated"
    echo "performing a clean install"
    npm ci
else
    echo "package-lock.json has NOT been updated"
    echo "no clean install needed"
fi



echo "---> building from source code <---"
npx tsc
echo "compile finished"


echo "===> post-receive hook finished <==="
```

And now the deploys work!